# When I start app-dynamics machine agent it is not writing any logs into logs folder

Tags: appdynamics

When I start app-dynamics machine agent (machineagent-bundle-64bit-linux-4.4.3.1214) it is not writing any logs into logs folder. How can I resolve this?

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-85-179 machine-agent]$ **/home/ec2-user/machine-agent/jre/bin/java -jar /home/ec2-user/machine-agent/machineagent.jar**
```

Results in:

```
Using Java Version [1.8.0_231] for Agent
Using Agent Version [Machine Agent v4.5.16.2357 GA compatible with 4.4.1.0 Build Date 2019-11-06 21:59:42]
[INFO] Agent logging directory set to: [/home/ec2-user/machine-agent]
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
```

..it just stops here.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you it couldn't find a log4j2.xml, log4j2-test.xml, log4j2.properties or log4j2-test.properties on the class path so it used the default configuration instead, which will log errors to the console.

To solve it you either need to put one of those files on the class path or set the log4j2.configurationFile system property to point to your configuration.